# FIFO number of processes, sustained growth

Tags: shell, process, process-management, multithreading

I have a FIFO question:

Why the fifo **thread_num** limit 2,
but number of processes, sustained growth when one process ends,
two processes start, and then got 3 processes.

sustained growth  2n-1

```
#!bin/bash
#exec clear file
mkdir -p xxx
thread_num=2
 
[ ! -p tmp ] && mkfifo tmp
exec 9<>tmp
 
for ((i=0;i<$thread_num;i++)); do
    echo >&9
done
echo "================start sh===================="
for i in  `cat shfiles.txt`;
do
        read -u 9
        {
                sh $i
                mv $i xxx/
                echo >&9
        } &
done
wait
exec 9>&-
rm tmp
echo "=================done===================="
exit 0
```

@Paul_Pedant
I can't add comment now.
This code is simplified, and I execute it in a folder, using the root account.

`shfiles.txt` is a collection of SH file paths.

In the executed file is the perforce command, like this:

20210326/archive13.sh

20210326/archive14.sh

```
p4 archive -D depot -t xxxxx#1
```

I use `ps -aux | grep sh` to view the current process, which is growing and ending.

Two processes are generated at the end of each process. 
So there are more and more processes.

I appear to have solved it, but I don't know why.
To modify the fifo 9 -> 7  like exec 7<>tmp.
Is that 9 Used by other processes?

Thank you all for helping me.
I got ps like this

```
sh -x ShArchiveCommand.sh 
sh -x ShArchiveCommand.sh 
sh -x ShArchiveCommand.sh 
20210326/ArchiveTList12.sh
20210326/ArchiveTList13.sh
```

and then after one hour

```
sh -x ShArchiveCommand.sh 
sh -x ShArchiveCommand.sh 
20210326/ArchiveTList12.sh
sh -x ShArchiveCommand.sh 
20210326/ArchiveTList14.sh
sh -x ShArchiveCommand.sh
20210326/ArchiveTList15.sh
```

and I check ArchiveTList12 not finished yet

a new exception

```
sh -x ShArchiveCommand.sh 
sh -x ShArchiveCommand.sh 
20210326/ArchiveTList12.sh
sh -x ShArchiveCommand.sh 
20210326/ArchiveTList13.sh
sh -x ShArchiveCommand.sh 
20210326/ArchiveTList14.sh
```

and I check ArchiveTList12，ArchiveTList13 not finished all

Comment: You may want to run that script under `env SHELLOPTS=xtrace ./that-script` to see what's going on.

Comment: [A] What are the contents of `shfiles.txt`? Each line is being run by `sh`, and could be doing anything they please. [B] How are you counting processes? `ps` and `pstree` will tell you actual running processes. But Bash (your outer script) will aggressively harvest child processes (so they disappear from `ps`) but continue to list them in the `jobs` list until the `wait` is invoked, which is after all the input has been read.

Comment: This has many issues. [A] The shebang is relative, and only valid when run in root directory, in which case the mkdir won't work. Maybe you are testing raw scripts as root in `/` ? [B] It throws six errors in shellcheck. [C] The `cat` will pass each input word (not line) to dash separately.

Comment: Points on your edits to the original post. [1] You are running the scripts under `sh`, which is usually a link to dash, ksh, or bash depending on your distro. So I don't know how to replicate your problem exactly. [2] Your `wait` is not called until after the `for .. done` loop completes. So probably the shells you see in `ps` are finished, but awaiting having their status requested. (Bash avoids this by collecting and storing results so `ps` does not see them.) [3] You get two shells per iteration -- a subshell running the `{ ... } &` and the one running `archive??.sh`.

Comment: My test script works identically with `dash 0.5.8-2.10`, `bash 4.4.20(1)` and `ksh 93u+ 2012-08-01`. Your `grep sh` is counting all root shells (and matches sh, dash, ksh and bash): you might try `ps -aux | grep '2021.*archive'` if all your script names are like that. But my `pstree -p "${PPID}"` shows the actual hierarchy of the current job nicely. 'Simplified' may be hiding the actual issue (e.g. additional background tasks, pipelines to compression tools, ... in the archive scripts).

Comment: @wangjiaying you appear to have two accounts [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/464036/wangjiaying) and [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/464038/wangjiaying). Please complete the registration process for one of them, then [Contact SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) to merge them so that you can continue managing your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting methodology, so I followed it up.

I have a diagnostic script that illustrates the operation. In particular, it labels each Tick ("permit to run") with a sequence number and time, like `[4] Sent 19:53:54`, so when it is read, it can be identified. As the sequence ends when the `shfiles.txt` ends, I also flush remaining Ticks.

I also marked all debug with the prefix `[ x ] &&` . These lines can be permanently removed, or just disabled by changing the x to a space. And I changed all the filenames.

My commands file `moonie.cmds` is this (each command identifies itself and makes the scheduling ragged):

```
echo One && sleep 8
echo Two && sleep 3
echo Three && sleep 6
echo Four && sleep 5
echo Five && sleep 9
```

These are simple commands, which I run using `bash -c`. Script names should be OK, but args and quoting in the .cmds file may be difficult. I couldn't see why you `mv` the scripts (?) to another directory after they are run, as I don't know what your `.cmds` file looks like.

I used `pstree` to show that my bash and outer script pids are constant, and the asynchronous subshell and the sleep run two at a time, as configured by the `threads` variable. I tested with 1, 2, 3, and 10 threads.

My script is this:

```
#! /bin/bash

Threads=2

mkdir -p moonie.dir     #.. Not used.

#.. Clean the named pipe and attach to fd9. 
rm -f moonie.fifo
mkfifo moonie.fifo
exec 9<>moonie.fifo
 
#.. Seed the fifo with required thread count.
for ((Seq = 1; Seq <= Threads; ++Seq)); do
    printf '[%s] Sent %(%T)T\n' "${Seq}" -1 >&9
done

echo "================ start sh ===================="

[ x ] && sleep 1    #.. Show we are waiting for the Ticks.

while IFS='' read -r Cmd; do    #.. Work through the command list.

    IFS='' read -r -u 9 Tick    #.. Wait for a free thread. 
    [ x ] && printf '%(%T)T Read Tick %s\n' -1 "${Tick}"

    {   #.. Launch a thread asynchronously.
        [ x ] && printf '%(%T)T Begin %s\n' -1 "${Cmd}"
        bash -c "${Cmd}"
        [ x ] && printf '%(%T)T Ended %s\n' -1 "${Cmd}"
        #.. Refresh its thread on completion.
        printf '[%s] Sent %(%T)T\n' "${Seq}" -1 >&9
    } &
    (( ++Seq ))     #.. Number Ticks for diagnostics.

    [ x ] && sleep 0.3              #.. Wait for the job to register.
    [ x ] && pstree -p "${PPID}"    #.. Show the running job hierarchy.

done < moonie.cmds

wait    #.. Wait for all threads to complete.

#.. Flush superfluous Ticks (timeout read because the fifo will hang).
while IFS='' read -r -t 1 -u 9 Tick; do
    [ x ] && printf '%(%T)T Discard Tick %s\n' -1 "${Tick}"
done

exec 9>&-       #.. Disconnect and remove the fifo.
rm moonie.fifo

echo "================= done ===================="
exit 0
```

The debug session was this:

```
================ start sh ====================
19:53:51 Read Tick [1] Sent 19:53:50
19:53:51 Begin echo One && sleep 8
One
bash(12037)───moonie(16150)─┬─moonie(16155)───sleep(16157)
                            └─pstree(16158)
19:53:51 Read Tick [2] Sent 19:53:50
19:53:51 Begin echo Two && sleep 3
Two
bash(12037)───moonie(16150)─┬─moonie(16155)───sleep(16157)
                            ├─moonie(16159)───sleep(16161)
                            └─pstree(16162)
19:53:54 Ended echo Two && sleep 3
19:53:54 Read Tick [4] Sent 19:53:54
19:53:54 Begin echo Three && sleep 6
Three
bash(12037)───moonie(16150)─┬─moonie(16155)───sleep(16157)
                            ├─moonie(16164)───sleep(16166)
                            └─pstree(16167)
19:53:59 Ended echo One && sleep 8
19:53:59 Read Tick [3] Sent 19:53:59
19:53:59 Begin echo Four && sleep 5
Four
bash(12037)───moonie(16150)─┬─moonie(16164)───sleep(16166)
                            ├─moonie(16168)───sleep(16170)
                            └─pstree(16171)
19:54:00 Ended echo Three && sleep 6
19:54:00 Read Tick [5] Sent 19:54:00
19:54:00 Begin echo Five && sleep 9
Five
bash(12037)───moonie(16150)─┬─moonie(16168)───sleep(16170)
                            ├─moonie(16172)───sleep(16174)
                            └─pstree(16175)
19:54:04 Ended echo Four && sleep 5
19:54:09 Ended echo Five && sleep 9
19:54:09 Discard Tick [6] Sent 19:54:04
19:54:09 Discard Tick [7] Sent 19:54:09
================= done ====================
```